# How to create or define a new target in a custom Xcode project template

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, project-template

***TL;DR:*** What XML snippets do I add to my TemplateInfo.plist files, to create a second compiler target when creating a new Xcode project?

While working on my own Xcode project template, I'm trying to have [KIF integration testing](https://github.com/square/KIF) working in a 'out of the box' sort of way. KIF requires you to [duplicate your regular target](https://github.com/square/KIF#create-a-testing-target) and then modify some properties. This is normally done manually, but it both takes time and leaves a margin for error, while it's so mundane it could be automated.

For clarity, I'm looking to create the **second target** in this screenshot **automatically**:

[image: Screenshot after manual duplication]

I got quite far with the whole template customization, but I just can't figure out how to create another target, even though the templates create one for unit testing if you hit that checkbox. *How does Apple do that*?

Have a look at [the template project over at my github repository](https://github.com/epologee/Project-Template-iOS). If you want to see what I'm doing with KIF (even though for the answer of this question this is should not be necessary), have a look at the plist in the [KIF Integrations.xctemplate](https://github.com/epologee/Project-Template-iOS/tree/master/template/Additions/KIF%20Integrations.xctemplate) folder.

Comment: [Calabash](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios), an automated testing-framework, does something similar.  
Alas, the sourcecode for the relevant CalabashSetup seems to be unavailable.
Maybe you could contact the author and find out how he did it?

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question correctly...

To duplicate the Build Target automatically without manually creating a new one and setting it up select the one you want to duplicate and press CMD+D

---

(Instructions on how to do the same things but with (the more likely) build schemes (for future users who wonder to this question) are below:

In xCode click Product (top bar... across from File, Edit, View, etc.) and then at the bottom of the drop-down menu click "New Scheme".

To duplicate your scheme (like you suggested) click "Edit Scheme" instead of "New Scheme" then click "Duplicate Scheme"

Comment: Sorry Albert, that's not at all what my question is about. It's about Xcode project templates and how to create a second target from within the template files. Thanks for noticing, @jrturton.

Comment: Okay:) I wasn't sure, that's why I prefaced it with "If I understand your question correctly..." haha! Good luck dude!