# Error building app for ios in phonegap (for android is working fine)

Tags: ios, cordova, build

I am developing an app with phonegap and I have always been testing the app using the android simulator and I have not had any problems, but I can not get it to work for iOS.

I'm working on a Mac OS mavericks and have installed Xcode.

When I run the command "phonegap run ios", I get the following:

```
[phonegap] detecting iOS SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] compiling iOS...
Build settings from command line:
ARCHS = i386
CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR = /Users/usuario/Desktop/desarrolloapp/nombreapp/platforms/ios/build/emulator
SDKROOT = iphonesimulator7.1
VALID_ARCHS = i386

xcodebuild: error: The project ‘NombreApp.xcodeproj’ does not contain a target named ‘NombreApp’.
[error] /Users/usuario/Desktop/desarrolloapp/nombreapp/platforms/ios/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 65
```

Any idea about what's going on?

EDIT: I solve this doing:

1. Remove ios folder from platforms.
2. Run again (phonegap run ios).
3. Install ios-sim with command sudo npm install -g ios-sim.
4. All worked fine!

A lot of thanks.

Best regards.

Comment: manually create target with name `NombreApp` in Xcode as [given here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14651166/how-to-create-or-define-a-new-target-in-a-custom-xcode-project-template).

Comment: The problem of target was solved, doing what you said.

Then I had a problem about a file libCordova.a which was not found.
After changing options in the build settings of Xcode project and without solving this, I did the next:

1. Remove ios folder from platforms.
2. Run again.
3. Install ios-sim with command sudo npm install -g ios-sim.
4. All worked fine!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually create target with name ***NombreApp*** in Xcode as given this link :

->
[How to create or define a new target in a custom Xcode project template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14651166/how-to-create-or-define-a-new-target-in-a-custom-xcode-project-template)

Regards,